# How to reorder/reshape N-D matrix in zigzag manner?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, zigzag-encoding

I would like to sort cells of tensor in this way

[image]

Note, that each cell is not a single value, but a stack of values (DCT components). So, the dimensions of original tensor is not 2D.